# JQuery Fade Slideshow bug

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow, settimeout, fadein

I made a slideshow of images in `jquery` using the `fadeIn` functionality. Now, the slideshow works fine except for one tiny problem. When it reaches the last image, it's supposed to return back and the first image is supposed to fade in. But, instead, the first image just shows; it doesn't fade in. Here's my jquery code below:

```
var index = 1;

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wallpaper:not(:nth-child(' + index + '))').css({ display : 'none' });
    slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    var $firstImg = $('.wallpaper:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    $('#para1 h3').text(index);
    if ($firstImg.next().length) {
    index ++;
    } else {
    index = 1;
}

var $nextImg = $('.wallpaper:nth-child(' + index + ')');

$nextImg.delay(6000).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    $firstImg.hide();
    $('#para1 h3').text(index); // This is just for debugging purposes
    $('#para2 h3').text($firstImg.attr('alt') + ' ' + $firstImg.css('display') + ' ' + 
    $nextImg.attr('alt') + ' ' + $nextImg.css('display')); // This too
    setTimeout(slideShow());
});
}
```

Help would really be appreciated.
In the answer I need to know why this is happening along with the solution. (i'm new)
Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is on the last function, `$firstImg.hide();` will just make it disappear at once. If `$nextImg` is not somehow z-indexed before $firstImg

Comment: It worked. But could you please tell me why it wasn't a problem during the first two images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images will fade in one by one, on top of one another, and the old image in the background will hide once the fade in has completed. The reason this works is because subsequent images are all shown on top of the previous.

With the last image, however, an image from the bottom will be faded in, but it will not be shown, as the top-most image is showing above it. The first image in the set will fade in in the background, and it will appear, suddenly, at `$firstImage.hide()`, when the image above it is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the last function run, `$firstImg.hide();` will just make it disappear at once, if $nextImg is not somehow z-indexed before $firstImg

On the previous runs, the pictures which are being faded in are *on top* of the previous picture. So the last picture is above the first one.

When you fade in the first one again at the end of this "loop", the last one is still on top, and will disappear only when you call `hide()`.